# VNC server can not auto start

Tags: vnc

I installed REALVNC VNC(R) Server 6.2.0 (r29523) ARMv6 (Aug 3 2017 18:32:53) in my Pi 3b board. The VNC server can not auto start when Pi reboot. I have to type the command " vncserver" to start VNC server, after that I can connect Pi from my PC through the VNC viewer.

In menu Preferences > Raspberry Pi Configuration > Interfaces, SSH and VNC are set to Enabled.

Run the command `sudo raspi-config`, and navigate to Advanced Options, there is no option of VNC.

Answer (score 0):

This is installing the x11vnc and run at boot, which is what I use as I had a lot of problems with RealVNC.

Install and set stored password

```
- sudo apt-get install x11vnc
- x11vnc -storepasswd
```

create autostart entry

```
- cd ~
- cd .config
- mkdir autostart
- cd autostart
- sudo nano x11vnc.desktop
```

paste following text:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=Application
Name=X11VNC
Comment=
Exec=x11vnc -forever -usepw -display :0 -ultrafilexfer
StartupNotify=false
Terminal=false
Hidden=false
```